# Parsing a string within a string?

Tags: php, parsing, variables, string

I have a function which accepts a string parameter such as: "var1=val1 var2=val2 var3='a list of vals'";

I need to parse this string and pick out the var/val combination's.  That is easy enough until introducing something like var3='a list of vals'.  Obviously I can't explode the string into an array using a white space delimiter which has me kind of stuck.  I want to create an array from this string with the var/val pairs properly assigned, how can I do this in a case where I have something like var3?

Comment: I am going to try the following approach: use space as a delimiter to explode string into array, walk array and if any of the members start with a single quote continue walking array until finding its matching end quote and "glue" the string back together.

Comment: I added a simple string parser to my answer below that seems to work.

Comment: Watch out for escaped single quotes then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the format of the string *is* set in stone, you could do something like:

```
$string = "var1=val1 var2=val2 var3='this is a test'";

$vars = array();
$i = 0;
while ($i < strlen($string)) {

    $eqIndex = strpos($string, "=", $i);
    $varName = substr($string, $i, $eqIndex - $i);

    $i = $eqIndex + 1;

    if ($string[$i] == "'") 
    {
        $varEndIndex = strpos($string, "'", ++$i);
    }
    else
    {
        $varEndIndex = strpos($string, " ", $i);
        if ($varEndIndex === FALSE) $varEndIndex = strlen($string);
    }

    $varValue = substr($string, $i, $varEndIndex - $i);

    $vars[$varName] = $varValue;

    $i = $varEndIndex + 1;
}

print_r($vars);
```

EDIT:

More robust function that handles escaped chars in the quoted values:

```
function getVarNameEnd($string, $offset) {

    $len = strlen($string);
    $i = $offset;
    while ($i < $len) {

        if ($string[$i] == "=")
            return $i;
        $i++;
    }

    return $len;
}

function getValueEnd($string, $offset) {

    $len = strlen($string);
    $i = $offset;
    if ($string[$i] == "'") {
        $quotedValue = true;
        $i++;
    }
    while ($i < $len) {

        if ($string[$i] == "\\" && $quotedValue)
            $i++;
        else if ($string[$i] == "'" && $quotedValue)
            return $i + 1;
        else if ($string[$i] == " " && !$quotedValue)
            return $i;
        $i++;
    }

    return $len;
}

function getVars($string) {

    $i = 0;
    $len = strlen($string);
    $vars = array();
    while ($i < $len) {

        $varEndIndex = getVarNameEnd($string, $i);
        $name = substr($string, $i, $varEndIndex - $i);
        $i = $varEndIndex + 1;

        $valEndIndex = getValueEnd($string, $i);
        $value = substr($string, $i, $valEndIndex - $i);
        $i = $valEndIndex + 1;

        $vars[$name] = $value;
    }

    return $vars;
}

$v = getVars("var1=var1 var2='this is a test' var3='this has an escaped \' in it' var4=lastval");
print_r($v);
```

Comment: What if '=' is part of the value in single quotes?

Comment: If you use query string syntax, single quotes and equal signs are escaped using the % character.

Comment: I added a solution for the type of string you provided.

Comment: This is working great for the example I gave, doing what I can now to try and "break" it :P -- THANKS.

Comment: This solution won't work when there are escaped single-quotes in the values.  Working on a better function for you

Comment: Excellent! How can I check up front (before parsing) to ensure that if one single quote exists that it has another?  Obviously they should always be in pairs.

Comment: Only having one problem at this juncture -- I can't find a test to catch the condition where:
"var1=val1 var2=this is a test" <-- notice the complete omission of single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is traditionally why query strings use & as the delimiter and not spaces.

If you can do that, then just use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the data out.

If not, you'll need to do regex:

```
preg_match_all('/(\S*)=('.*?'|\S*)/g', $your_string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: The immediate problem with your current code is .* is greedy - it will match to the last ', which is too much.

Comment: Yeah, just did the edit when i saw your comment merk. Not sure why I'm rated down though now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to find all matching var=val pairs, such as

```
(\w[0-9A-Za-z]+)=(\'?\w([0-9A-Za-z ]|\\\'|\\=)+\'?)
```

then you can use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to parse them from there, if the string of the second group starts with a ' character you can parse the list.

Comment: Your current version won't parse values with spaces (\w doesn't include spaces). Also, what happens with escaped single quotes which are part of the value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this problem cannot be solved with simple regex or by simple splitting. Have a look at the [str_getcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function in PHP 5.3. I think you can make it do exactly what you want.

```
array str_getcsv  ( string $input  [, string $delimiter  [, string $enclosure  [, string $escape  ]]] )
```

You can specify delimiter as space instead of comma and enclosure as single quote instead of double quote. If you can, dig up the implementation of this function, understand it, and learn from it. Otherwise get PHP 5.3 to use it.

**Edit:** There, if you don't have PHP 5.3:

```
if(!function_exists('str_getcsv')) {
    function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ",", $enclosure = '"', $escape = "\\") {
        $fp = fopen("php://memory", 'r+');
        fputs($fp, $input);
        rewind($fp);
        $data = fgetcsv($fp, null, $delimiter, $enclosure); // $escape only got added in 5.3.0
        fclose($fp);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Credit: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-str-getcsv-function/

**Edit:** Here's the implementation in Perl: [Text::CSV](http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). You can download the source and see the algorithms. If you are up for it :)

Comment: That function does appear to do what I need to do however we haven't upgraded to 5.3 yet...  *Sigh*

Comment: Then find its definition and copy it :)

Comment: This is a LOT of work for something you can easily do with regex. You also might not have the permissions necessary to run that function depending on the environment.

Comment: Unfortunately this function doesn't parse out the single quoted strings properly.  
str_getcsv("var1=test1 var2='testing 1 2 3...'", " ", "'");
results in an array with 5 members.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't given the whole thing much thought, but what about this? Maybe A LITTLE too much code for such a small task :)

```
<?php
  function parse_vars($string)
  {
    $exploded = explode(" ", $string);
    $return = array();
    foreach($exploded AS $entry){
      if(strpos($entry, "=") === false){      
        $return[$current] .= " ".$entry;
      }else{
        list($key, $value) = explode("=", $entry);
        $return[$key] = $value;
        $current = $key;
      }
    }   
    return $return;
  }

  $string = "var1=val1 var2=val2 var3='a list of vals'";
  print_r(parse_vars($string));
  die();
?>
```

By the way I still prefer the regex solution with `"(\S*)=('.*?'|\S*)"` ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want the parse_str() function?

Here's the example from PHP.net:

```
<?php
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz

?>
```

It seems to do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, you can't change it.  I would use an algorithm like this:

**1)** Replace all strings contained inside quotes with a unique Id, and store the ID in an array.

So

> var1=val1 var2=val2 var3='a list of vals'

becomes

> var1=val1 var2=val2 var3=asifab
>
> array("asifab" => 'a list of vals')

**2)** Split by spaces

> array("var1=val1", "var2=val2", "var3=asifab")
>
> array("asifab" => 'a list of vals')

**3)** split by equal signs

> array("var1"=>"val1", "var2"=>"val2", "var3"=>"asifab")
>
> array("asifab" => 'a list of vals')

**4)** For each value, see if it's in your array, and if it is, split the array value by spaces and use that as the value

> array("var1"=>"val1", "var2"=>"val2", "var3"=>array("a", "list", "of", "values"))

Comment: Unfortunately yes I am stick working within this structure. The function prototype requires that the list of var/vals be passed as a single string.

Comment: $argument in this case is a string though so I can't traverse it with foreach().

Answer (score -1):

Use RegEx with `preg_split()`?

I'm not great with RE, but I'm sure you can use this to prevent splitting the string inside the single quotes.