# how to parse name = value pairs in php ? what is at least satisfactory approach?

Tags: php, parsing

Satisfactory that is to not go into functions that eat much time.

Format of the data:
It is basically similar to the HTML tag parameters, but not quite.

````
<name1=value1 name2=value2 [here can be any whitespace characters]
33=55 "name with spaces and ="="value with spaces and '" '"title"'="can't" "in
names"="and
values can be tabs and new lines"
double"and_single'quotes=are_allowed_in_names_and_values_if_there_is_no_whitespace_in_it
"escaping is ""sql-like"""='the same with ''single quotes'''
`third option`=`are "backticks" that also can be ``escaped```>
````

Is this format called somehow ? I 'invented' it myself but I highly doubt that no one came up with this idea before, maybe it (or very similar format, for example with slash escaping) already has a parsing function in php ?

If not, how to write my own, using regexes, string operations, some kind of buffers, accumulators ? I've never written any parser myself yet.

Comment: Why not change it to XML? Then you would have a wide variety of parsers at your disposal.

Comment: in XML there's not possible to have names with spaces and other chars than [a-z].

Comment: Agree with Pekka, XML would be much better for the task. Also, it might be a good idea to use JSON (built-in functions `json_encode` and `json_decode`) or [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/). Both are less verbose than XML and suitable for the task.

Comment: xml is like violence. if you're not getting the result you need, you're not using enough of it. If you put an xml tag into your 'valid-named' tag and put a name/value pair in there where you provide the real name with all the characters you cannot use in your tag name (spaces etc)? Just my two cents.

Comment: That's a completely barmy format. It's impossible to read and no parser exists for it. Why not just use a comprehensible system? The `ini_file` format, for example.

Comment: Could be done. But the escaping rules (if any) are totally unclear.

Comment: "As I have a whim of not using a conventional format, I've invented a weird one. Now give me functions to handle it". Very nice.

Comment: Not give but I ask how approach to take to make one, I don't ask you to write it for me.

Comment: I can't understand how it is impossible to read ? It is quite simple and made for simple data, but is robust enough to not go stupid when some exception like space or new line in a name of the value arises. In 99% of the time it would be simply name1=value1 name2=value2 and so on. For me the XML is hard to read, to much unnecessary chars compared to the data.

Comment: Have you considered JSON or YAML? Both of these retain the simplicity of your key-value pairs, (a) have fast parsers and generators written for you; (b) can handle more complex stuff as well.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070677/parsing-a-string-within-a-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

````php
$in = <<<BLOCK
name1=value1 

name2=value2 [here can be any whitespace characters]

33=55 

"name with spaces and ="="value with spaces and '" 

'"title"'="can't" 

"in names"="and
  values can be tabs and new lines"

double"and_single'quotes=are_allowed_in_names_and_values_if_there_is_no_whitespace_in_it

"escaping is ""sql-like"""='the same with ''single quotes'''

`third option`=`are "backticks" that also can be ``escaped```
BLOCK;

$string = "(?:                    # open non-capture group
             \"(?:\"\"|[^\"])+\"  # match a double quoted string
           | '(?:''|[^'])+'       # OR match a single quoted string
           | `(?:``|[^`])+`       # OR match a back-ticked string
           )                      # close non-capture group
          ";

$key    = "(                      # start capture group 1
             $string              # match any string
           | [^=\s]+              # OR match one or more chars other than '=' and space-chars
           )                      # end capture group 1
          ";

$value  = "(                      # start capture group 2
             $string              # match any string
           | [^\r\n]+             # OR match one or more chars other than '=' and space-chars
           )                      # end capture group 2
          ";

$regex = "/$key=$value/x"; // combine the patterns

preg_match_all($regex, $in, $matches);

$key_value_pairs = sizeof($matches[0]);

for($index = 0; $index < $key_value_pairs; $index++) {
  echo "===============================================\n" . 
       "KEY:\n" . $matches[1][$index] . "\n" .
       "VALUE:\n" . $matches[2][$index] . "\n";
}
````

which will print the following:

````
===============================================
KEY:
name1
VALUE:
value1 
===============================================
KEY:
name2
VALUE:
value2 [here can be any whitespace characters]
===============================================
KEY:
33
VALUE:
55 
===============================================
KEY:
"name with spaces and ="
VALUE:
"value with spaces and '"
===============================================
KEY:
'"title"'
VALUE:
"can't"
===============================================
KEY:
"in names"
VALUE:
"and
  values can be tabs and new lines"
===============================================
KEY:
double"and_single'quotes
VALUE:
are_allowed_in_names_and_values_if_there_is_no_whitespace_in_it
===============================================
KEY:
"escaping is ""sql-like"""
VALUE:
'the same with ''single quotes'''
===============================================
KEY:
`third option`
VALUE:
`are "backticks" that also can be ``escaped```
````

Use, and maintain, at your own risk!

Comment: Every format is horrific if you don't have a fast C parser for it build in the language. The fact that we are using XML and not some other more or less horrific (relative to it) format is just a historical coincidence. Just like in English and Spanish, when in first you have a medieval phonology binded to today's pronunciation, and in second (and in many other langs) you basically write as you speak but also with now-unlogical scars of past times.

Comment: @rsk82, note the smiley in my answer.

Comment: And again I write (for people with ADHD ;), the data is horrific, the format wasn't really meant for that kind of stuff, just has it to be robust enough to not break if horrific data come in.    Thanks for an answer!

Comment: this answer is offtopic as the OP stated that he didn't ask for the function to be written for him.

Comment: I did not ask specifically, but if someone is kind, I appreciate it. I thought that was understood. Now I'm playing with it to make it as fast as possible, that is a nice piece of regex, I understood from this example more than from no-one manual.

Comment: the `S` pattern modifier does a much good here in terms of speed in a loop, also taking the regex string to a static variable speeds up running in a loop

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, I quickly glanced over the input and wrote a quick hack instead of explaining how such a regex would look like, that doesn't make it off topic. Funny that such critique, and probably the down-vote, is coming from _you_ of all people: someone who produces so much low quality answers here on SO. Besides, how can an (accepted!) answer on a (non-off topic) question on SO be off topic? –

Answer (score 1):

an example of XML allowing spaces in names

```
<item>
 <name>name with spaces</name>
 <value>
   value with spaces
   and linebreaks
 </value>
</item>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer, I hate doing XML for everything, no matter how the whole world is loving it. (Of course it is usable for some kind of stuff, and it is not a bad format per se, but it has it's limitations, and too much overhead when data is really simple.)